# prolog make a list of arithmetic expressions (addition) from two other lists

Tags: prolog

I need to write a predicate that creates a list of arithmetic expressions from two lists (possibly of different lengths). Example: p([1,3,5,7],[2,4,6],[1+2,3+4,5+6]) – true.

I wrote as follows, but there is a small problem. i got such result, when goal looks like this: fp([1,3,5,7],[2,4,6],X), result: [3,7,11] tell me how I can achieve such a result, which should be [1+2,3+4,5+6]?  I understand that I have to write the strings "X+Y" to the list Z, but I do not know how to implement this, since I am a complete noob in the prologue

(this is not swi prolog, this is visual prolog 5.2)

```
domains
i=integer
il=i*
predicates
f(il,il,il)
clauses
f([],_,[]):-!.
f(_,[],[]):-!.
f([X|T1],[Y|T2],[Z|T3]):-Z=X+Y,f(T1,T2,T3).
goal
f([1,3,5,7],[2,4,6,8,10,12],R).
```

Comment: Related (and elegant): https://professor-fish.blogspot.com/2009/11/countdown-with-prolog.html

Comment: Your code works in SWI Prolog, so it seems like Visual Prolog treats `Z=X+Y` as evaluating an expression, rather than unifying Prolog terms. I can't quickly find anything on the Visual Prolog website documentation about that, but what if you change `f([X|T1],[Y|T2],[Z|T3]):-Z=X+Y,f(T1,T2,T3).` to `f([X|T1],[Y|T2],[X+Y|T3]):-f(T1,T2,T3).` ?